# Google Cloud Build Docker build-arg from file

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I have a problem when I use Google Cloud Build. I can't pass the key into docker by cloudbuild.yaml

Google buildfile.yaml:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - kms
  - decrypt
  - --ciphertext-file=A.enc
  - --plaintext-file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
  - --location=global
  - --keyring=keyringxxx
  - --key=keyxxx
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
    'build', '.',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/xxx:latest',
    '--build-arg', 'READ_KEY=`cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa`'
  ]
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.11 AS builder

ARG READ_KEY
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh &&  \
    echo "$READ_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/XXXX.insteadOf https://github.com/XXXX

......
```

The above code failed. `cat` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GCloud Docker Builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile-18.09.0#L19) is using the Exec form of [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).  Your arguments from the cloudbuild.yaml are not being passed to a shell, thus your `cat` will not be executed.

Why not direct KMS to write the `id_rsa` directly to the `/workspace` and do away with the `ssh` volume altogether?

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - kms
  - decrypt
  - --ciphertext-file=A.enc
  - --plaintext-file=/workspace/id_rsa
  - --location=global
  - --keyring=keyringxxx
  - --key=keyxxx
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
    'build', '.',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/xxx:latest'
  ]
```

And the Dockerfile becomes:

```
FROM golang:1.11 AS builder

RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh
COPY id_rsa ~/.ssh/
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    chmod -R 0600 ~/.ssh/ && \
    git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com
```

Don't forget to mount that `.gitconfig` into the additional build steps.  I just make it part of my CI build script, rather than requiring the extra `volume`.

Answer (score 1):

The .ssh directory needs to have the right permissions

```
RUN mkdir -m 700 -p ~/.ssh &&
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having problems with the step:

```
COPY id_rsa ~/.ssh/
```

Where the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is not persistent inside the docker build, workaround that worked for me was copying the file first to a directory inside the App files, and then copying it to the final directory:

```
ADD id_rsa /app/id_rsa
RUN cp /app/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'm not sure why this worked but well, here you go.